# Show $\phi^*, \phi_*: L(V,V) \to L(V,V)$ given by $\phi_*(\psi)=\phi \circ\psi, \phi^*(\psi)=\psi \circ\phi$ are linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $k$ be a field and $\phi: V \to V$ a linear transformation over $k$. I want to show that $\phi^*, \phi_*: L(V,V) \to L(V,V)$ given by
$$\phi_*(\psi)=\phi \circ\psi$$ $$\phi^*(\psi)=\psi \circ\phi$$
are linear transformations.

The first one seems pretty obvious:
$$\phi_*(\psi_1+\psi_2)=\phi \circ(\psi_1+\psi_2)=\phi(\psi_1+\psi_2)= \phi(\psi_1)+\phi(\psi_2)=\phi_*(\psi_1)+\phi_*(\psi_2)$$
by linearity of $\phi$.

I have no idea how to approach the second one, though, since we don't know anything about the linearity of $\psi$. Any hints?

Comment: Is $L(V,V)$ the space of all linear transformations from $V$ to $V$? If so, we know $\psi$ is linear. In this case, $\phi^*(\psi_1+\psi_2) = (\psi_1+\psi_2)(\phi) = \psi_1\circ \phi + \psi_2 \circ \phi  = \phi^\star(\psi_1) + \phi^\star(\psi_2)$.

Comment: @walkar Absolutely right, got lost in notation. Thanks!